# Get attribute value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get the attribute value in jQuery, but isn't working, My code reports undefined. Here is an example:

```js
console.log($(".btn-causas input").find(".active input").attr('d'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-causas" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-info ">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="optiond1" class="btncauses" autocomplete="off" d="security_alert">Security
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-info ">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="optiond1" class="btncauses" autocomplete="off" d="strike">Strike
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-info active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="optiond1" class="btncauses" autocomplete="off" d="dontknow">I DON'T
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have any `<input>` tag that has `<element class="active"><input>` inside...

Comment: `.find()` looks for *decendants* of the element you specify. So by doing `$(input).find('.active')` you're looking for `.active` elements *inside* `input`. Because this doesn't exist, you'll get an `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector could be simply done like :

```
$(".btn-causas .active input").attr('d');
```

Hope this helps.

```js
console.log( $(".btn-causas .active input").attr('d') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-causas" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-info ">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="optiond1" class="btncauses" autocomplete="off" d="security_alert"> Security
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-info ">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="optiond1" class="btncauses" autocomplete="off" d="strike"> Strike
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-info active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="optiond1" class="btncauses" autocomplete="off" d="dontknow"> I DON'T
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is that you rename the attribute `d` for `data-name` and you can get very easy that value with this code:

**Html:**

```
<input type="radio" name="options" id="optiond1" class="btncauses" autocomplete="off" data-name="dontknow">
```

**Jquery:**

```
var value = $('input[name="options"]:checked').data('name');
alert(value);
```

This is the best way to do that, this code retrieve the value of a checked input radio with the attribute data-name

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying wrong selector `.btn-causas input`, instead use this `.btn-causas`, See the code below:

> Make jQuery find the `inputs` inside div - `.btn-causas` instead of finding it inside inputs, as you've done. Inputs doesn't contains a child elements, so you can't find elements inside it.

```js
$(function() {
 console.log($(".btn-causas").find(".active input").attr('d'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-causas" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-info ">
  <input type="radio" name="options" id="optiond1" class="btncauses" autocomplete="off" d="security_alert"> Security
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-info ">
  <input type="radio" name="options" id="optiond1" class="btncauses" autocomplete="off" d="strike"> Strike
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-info active">
  <input type="radio" name="options" id="optiond1" class="btncauses" autocomplete="off" d="dontknow"> I DON'T
  </label>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have active class but as per my understanding you are trying to get selected radio buttons' attribute so try :checked on input